# Typescript multi generics object declaration

Tags: typescript, generics, types, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm struggling to type a function with this behaviour :
given a object `conf` with an undefined number of keys, each key being an object with `value` and `type` properties, the function should return an object with the same properties and only `value` as `value`.

So to be clear, this is an example of function input:

```
{
  foo: {value: 1, type: 'number'},
  bar: {value: 'hello', type: 'string'}
}
```

and the corresponding output:

```
{
  foo: 1,
  bar: 'hello'
}
```

Here is what I've written so far:

```js
type TypeWithName<T extends string> = 
  T extends 'number' ? number :
  T extends 'boolean' ? boolean : 
  T extends 'undefined' ? undefined :
  T extends 'array' ? string[] :
  string

declare function f<T extends string>(conf: {
  [key: string]: { default: TypeWithName<T>; type: T }
}): { [P in keyof typeof conf]: TypeWithName<T> }
```

That is obviously not correct since :

1. **T** can only take one type at a time (the example above will throw an error on property `bar`)
2. The return type has an undefined number of keys, instead of being all and only keys present in input object.

But I am a little lost here and don't really know where to look, nor if that's even possible.

Comment: Do you need `f()` to care about the input value properties having the right relationship between their `value` and `type` properties?  If so, what strings can `type` be?  It looks *almost* like the runtime output of `typeof value` except that there's no `"array"` primitive (it would be `object` at runtime).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach would be to use a mapping interface from `type` property string to `value` type instead of a conditional type; you might be able to use a conditional type here but it's easier to work with interfaces in the type system:

```
interface TypeMap {
  number: number;
  boolean: boolean;
  undefined: undefined;
  string: string;
  object: object | null;
}
```

I assumed you wanted `"string"` to map to `string`, and I added `"object"`.  If you want `"array"` to map to `string[]` you can do that, I guess.

Then I want to use `TypeMap` to make a union type called `Config` representing the constraint between `value` and `type`, like this:

```
type Config = {
  [K in keyof TypeMap]: { value: TypeMap[K]; type: K }
}[keyof TypeMap];
```

If you inspect that, it is equivalent to:

```
type Config = {
    value: number;
    type: "number";
} | {
    value: boolean;
    type: "boolean";
} | {
    value: undefined;
    type: "undefined";
} | {
    value: string;
    type: "string";
} | {
    value: object | null;
    type: "object";
}
```

Now the `f` function is generic in `T`, an object type whose keys are whatever and whose properties are `Config`, represented by the constraint `Record<keyof T, Config>`.  The input type is `T`, and the output type [maps](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) each property in `T` to its `value` property:

```
declare function f<T extends Record<keyof T, Config>>(
  t: T
): { [K in keyof T]: T[K]["value"] };
```

Let's see if it works:

```
const output = f({
  foo: { value: 1, type: "number" },
  bar: { value: "hello", type: "string" }
}); 
// const output: { foo: number;  bar: string; }
```

I think that's the output type you're expecting, right?  If you need a narrower type (where e.g., `foo` is of *type* `1` instead of `number`), you can use a [`const` assertion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#const-assertions) in the input:

```
const outputNarrower = f({
  foo: { value: 1, type: "number" },
  bar: { value: "hello", type: "string" }
} as const); 
// const outputNarrower: { foo: 1; bar: "hello"; }
```

Finally, you can see that the input to `f()` is constrained so that you can't give a mismatching `value`/`type` pair:

```
f({
  chicken: { value: 123, type: "string" }, // error!
  cow: { value: "abc", type: "string" }
});
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOECydPIDeAsAFDLIgCuAtgEbQBcltDUA3GRXQPY8A2EOCGa8BQkJ3LIqIACYQYoCHOayFSkCqkUAzmCigA5s32GQRnch50AVhARhmN+4+QAfFv35SAvmTIwLBQAYR4QJSNkAF4iLmQAbQBpZFBkAGsIdB4YNGC8TABdZkJkADc4fioIZgxsAuTC9mQg7GYU-1JfBMzs3LrcfCaA0gB6ACpkQODkMIjgKNiSaQoKqpqWemgrClaNgCJqLah9vw84lfLK6tE+QWEdluDmfbF7kFOyX3PlilXrjbqRTKOSPPYvIGaFSfLo-eL-damAzGMHPZD7MzGGHfTy-P5rG7WOwOMDnajeVFtdEuEnYsjjUYjBQIfhwKAoGCyRzAcLIGAAHlQyAgAA9IPJdMgAEoOHhQOT83o5NAAGlm4UiAD5NQAKeJONBkACUJUSKTSSv6xTQjQS+wJEH2hWQvikZAQ4X01ioYEwPpifJ1eJgfFNDuYAEY1eD0Uc2PsXSr4nQ2WGAS8ABYQbw8fbRtEY5EWBOdXxGqSjUbID0gL08H1+g2lEM8Zhx7bcVPITEWZqdd2e0n130+gBybKgPAA7tAAzAg-EW2nEcgo08qYdWNAS0npCmoMvCfsszm8+uDj2jCWvsg4JKa-py2RK9XB96R2Bx1BJzOD0Q+aGq7NPumbZvwuZ9iM854ggGbAAgmQiP+4argATAAzPmG6XjuyAvtAk5QAAhPEHpToeBxwHQCBnjGhbmFeLpfE+pBAA)

Comment: Okay, that's very smart and well detailed, thank a lot ! I learn a few things thanks to you. `value` is optional in my real case application, but I can work from there and definitively find a complete solution. Again, thank you sir !

Answer (score 1):

You could try an approach along these lines:

```js
const conf = {
  foo: { value: 1, type: "number" },
  bar: { value: "hello", type: "string" }
};

type Input = {
  [key: string]: { value: any; type: string };
};

type Output<U extends Input> = { [Key in keyof U]: U[Key]["value"] };

function f<T extends Input>(input: T): Output<T> {
  // Details...
}

const returned = f(conf);

returned.foo // number
returned.bar // string
```

[TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBKYDMYF4YG8BQMYJCAXOjAG4CGANgK4CmhAjADQxQCeADrTAERiUC2AI2oAnLjAC+DLDAGlhhNCQo1CXABbVy5EFyasOq6MICWYAOZjxGcQG4MGfdRgBJMG0qxUmbAG0A1tQshEamZgC6CkpUnKRgLDbM7Jwh5hJ2tvaOMADyHu5QADwAqjDUAB5Q1GAAJhAubh4AfChEPgDSgTCmMAEsIEhFETBF7YFhPlxk0VxhafYIlGDAUMbgOAUAKqUVVbX1+Y0AFKb5hBsAlIS5UPmbzd4wAPSPMAAi1FCkxuQQAHT-1ns8GgMGEH0owjA1GqLQQh3gCHOdgwYKgEKh1V+uBATxevEEIhR4Mh0N+smEuJgKTMGCAA)

Comment: That a nice solution, but it constraint the type of `Output[key]` to the type of `Input[key][value]`. What I'm trying to do is constraining the type of `Output[key]` to the `Input[key][type]` with the help of my **TypeWithName** type.

Comment: Ahh, got it. I misunderstood. Do you need a `type` key if it can be inferred?

Comment: Yeah, I simplified the problem here for asking the question, but in my case the value will be optional and used only as a default one.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be enough..... key is using 'any'

```js
function change(x:any) {
  let y:any={};
  for(let c in x){
    console.log(c)
    y[c] = x[c].value;
  }
  return y;
}

let x={
  'foo': {value: 1, type: 'number'},
  'bar': {value: 'hello', type: 'string'}
};

console.log(change(x));
```